# jQuery submitting form of javascript arrays

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Okay so basically i'm trying to submit a form with some javascript arrays.

I expected this to take the form add the data to hidden fields and then post it automatically.

However I'm getting a strange error.

1. <s>The fields added dynamically aren't coming as hidden and are showing on screen.</s>
2. The code is working extremely slowly(running this locally so I can't imagine why)
3. It doesn't link to the PHP page but instead says: The connection to 10.0.0.2 was interrupted.(NOTE: The PHP page is valid and can be visited otherwise)

In this code correct and answers are javascript arrays

```
$("#questionForm").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
               var cform = $('<form></form>');
               cform.attr("method", "post");
               cform.attr("action"," <?php echo base_url()?>index.php/TestMaker/endTest");
               var cfield = $('<input></input>');
               cfield.attr("type", "hidden");
               cfield.attr("name", "correct");
               cfield.attr("value", correct);
               cform.append(cfield);
               cfield=$('<input></input>');
               cfield.attr("type","hidden");
               cfield.attr("name", "answers");
               cfield.attr("value", answers);
               cform.append(cfield);
               $(document.body).append(cform);
               cform.submit();
});
```

---

### EDIT

Okay the hidden part is fixed. Error in the second field. Didn't set it hidden.
Server Side Code:
    class TestMaker extends CI_Controller{

```
 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
 }

 function endTest(){
    $correct_arr=$_POST('correct');
    echo "hi";
    //$question_ids=$_POST('question_ids');
    //$question_types=$_POST('question_type');
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the reason your input is not hidden is that you modify the variable appending it, but the html has not been generated. Instead of re-assigning your `cfield`, try creating a new var.

Comment: What is the generated code, you might be missing a `/` between your `base_url()` call and index?

Comment: The first input is actually hidden, but you forgot to set the second's `type` to `hidden` as well. About the submission of the form, check what is there URL generated, as @jaudette said.

Comment: The endpoint works for `GET` and not for `POST`? As far as I can understand without the missing server side code this question won't go anywhere

Comment: You're still failing on the second input field, it should be `"hidden"`, not `hidden`. About your other problem, as @Alexander said, the server-side code would help a lot.

Comment: Added the server side code above. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the $_POST array wrongly, the correct way of accessing an array in PHP is using square brackets `[]`, like this:

```
$correct_arr = $_POST['correct'];
```

Also, if you're using CI, there's a [input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) which wraps the $_POST array and is quite helpful, which can be used this way:

```
$correct_arr = $this->input->post('correct');
```

Comment: Yeah. Nice one. Can't believe I missed it. But how come it showed an error connecting to the URL though? I mean wouldn't a PHP error or CI error show up?

Comment: Ye, a PHP error should have pop up, I don't know why it didn't though.